# C++ changing output on console

Tags: c++, console

What is the easiest way to display changing numbers in the console? I have a normal command line program in C++ which uses `cout`, but I'd like to display a percentage number representing the progress which counts up to 100 without printing a new line. How is that done? (If it matters: I'm on Windows 7)

Comment: So you mean to say print and erase numbers?

Comment: @Ringo: yes. You could also extend this to the general question: How would I change anything which I have earlier printed to the console? What I've also seen and find interesting: change the color of the output text.

Comment: @Nawaz: what is the `commandline` tag for?

Comment: commandline is what where you type commands, not where ouput gets printed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When I’ve needed that I have just output a **carriage return** character, in C++ `\r`.

Remember to **flush** the output each time, e.g.

```
cout << "\r" << x << "% completed.       " << flush;
```

The **spaces** at the end to clear previous output on the line in case of Microsoft-like fluctuating progress.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Use the backspace character.

```
cout << "10%";
// ...
cout << "\b\b\b20%";
```

Answer (score 6):

I normally place a carriage return after the progress information.  That way, any other output will appear normal (as long as it has enough characters in the line to completely overwrite the progress info).

```
    cerr<<percentage<<"% \r";
```

By the way, I prefer to use cerr instead of cout for this kind of status/diagnostic information so that cout can be reserved for real content.  This way you can redirect the normal program output to a file and still see the progress in the console.  Also, with cerr, you don't have to use "flush".

Comment: But you'd hardly pass a file to Huffman compression via stdin/stdout, would you?

Comment: @Felix: I certainly would!  But maybe not on Windows.  As I recall, you have to use non-standard calls to tell Microsoft's version of the C++ streams library not to modify "\r\n" sequences that might occur in your data stream by chance.  On Linux, this kind of use of stdin/stout is very powerful and very common.