# Basic terminal output using C++ - Questions

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, terminal, clang

Well, the question may sound a bit too vague but here's 2 things I need to do and I'd definitely need some input on this :

- **Output something (e.g. using `cout`) with color** *(note: My `TERM` environment variable is set to `xterm-color` if that makes any difference; also, is there any uniform way to output colored text that's compatible with both pure mac and *nix terminals in general, so that the code is portable)*
- **Output something at the same position on the terminal screen.** OK, this may sound confusing too. Let's take a terminal app which simply outputs a progress percentage. It normally won't start a new line for that. The new value is shown at the very same spot. How is this doable? *(Being a once Borland Pascal guy from the good old DOS days, the only thing I could think of is something to do with accessing video memory directly... or not?)*

So... any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982652/c-changing-output-on-console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library. And [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) can also be used for coloring.

Comment: Thanks; I'll have a look into it. :-)

Comment: Chances are that `curses` is the wrong choice for any new application.  The `ANSI escape codes` is a great resource however.

Answer (score 2):

1)

You can try Color cout , but that is not protable. I tried (ANSI escape codes) something like

```
cout << "\033[1;31mbold red text\033[0m\n";

cout << "\33[0;31m" << "Enter Your String here" << "\33[0m" << std::endl ;
```

You can also look at
[How do I output coloured text to a Linux terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616906/how-do-i-output-coloured-text-to-a-linux-terminal)

2)

Are you looking for something like watch or top like app which are showing output at the same spot.